# What are the common tools to build a .deb installation file for applications written in perl?

Tags: perl, debian, deb

So I have some source code and I need to put it in a .deb binary so I can easily deploy on my server. I seem to be having trouble find good easy to use tools that will enable me to do so. The source code is in Perl. And I *do* know all of its dependencies.

My question is do you know/use such tool? Which do you recommend for a beginner?

Answer (score 6):

Debian has a Perl module specific deb builder in the form of dh-make-perl. Debian Administration has [an article explaining how to use it](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/78).

Comment: that's sweet. could you tell I'm doing C/C++/C# only :)

Comment: Is there a further simplication if the perl module is pure perl? The article seems to be more for building perl modules that depend on other compiled code. (On a side note, it sure would be nice if they could use cpan for their builds)

Comment: As a simple example, this command will download a CPAN distribution and generate a .deb: `dh-make-perl --build --cpan Encoding::FixLatin`.  Or if you have your own code locally organised in the style of a CPAN distribution then you can run `dh-make-perl --build .` to debianise it.  Note a CPAN distribution can include scripts for the bin directory as well as modules for the lib.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `debhelper`. You might look at how other perl application are packaged, especially with respect to

- Installation location
- Dependency management

Here is a raw list of what I can think of

- debhelper (`dh_make`) - tool that converts source archives into Debian package source
- checkinstall - create .deb package from a monitored install using custom scripts/make
- debuild - build from existing source package

Start from existing package:

- `sudo apt-get build-dep <pkgname>; apt-get source <pkgname>; cd <pkgname>-<version>/; debuild -S`

  - alternatively: apt-get source  --compile

Note that `apt-get source` will usually print the dev repo for the package source on the console, so you can then `bzr branch lp:....` or `git clone ...` to contribute patches directly.

If you have a devkey (signup for one on launchpad.net) you can create a PPA (package archive). You can upload source packages using `dput` and these will get automatically built on the build farm for all applicable distributions/architecture.

If you want to mimick building in a virtual 'bare' container, look at `pdebuild` (creates chroot for the target distribution/series).

If you want to integrate with common other tools (vim, git-dch: manage changelogs) etc. look at git-buildpackage, devscripts, vim-addon-manager, debian-keyring, debian-goodies, gnome-pkg-tools, dpkg-dev

That's my braindump for the moment. I learned this the hard way over the course of 6+ months. Here are some valuable resources:

[Debian New Maintainers' Guide](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/)

Comment: Is there a good howto or reduction of the Debian New Maintainer's Guide that skips all the stuff about how new applications should behave and concentrates solely on documenting how to use the packaging tools in simple cases and later with more advanced features?